# Is this a correct use case diagram?

Tags: uml

I'm trying to write an use for shopping online . Customer can search for their desired item and add them to the shopping cart,but when they decide to check out, they need to log in with their account. But what happen if customer  already logged in ? Is my diagram still correct ? If not, How can I modify it ?

[image]

Comment: The question is OK for the first time. +1 and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the use case diagram as a workflow editor, which is incorrect.

Use case diagrams are used to indicate the actions that a user can take to accomplish something. They do not represent the sequence of these actions. Each use case starts from a specific user action, and not as a side effect of another use case.

In your diagram, the "Search" use case is fine, but the display of the result is part of that use case. It would not be very useful if the system would just display a "search complete" result and then force the user to do some action to view the result... Although you have an `<<include>>` relationship, that it not what it means.

One example for `<<include>>` is one for a Login use case. The Customer could login on their own before doing anything else or the login could be triggered by another use case, such as Check Out. Login would therefore be a use case on its own and it would also be `<<include>>` by the Check Out use case.

Add to Cart is a use case that should be triggered directly by the Customer. It is not something that is triggered automatically - the Customer needs to do something.

The same applies to the Make Payment use case. I would think that the Customer needs to perform an explicit action in order to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Any use case must be connected to some actor(s). So, you should add connections.

The CheckOut use case is strange and inunderstandable. I don't know any action in net stores, that includes both login and payment. If you mean ordering, the login or payment are additional separate use cases, that are connected to ordering by some conditions that could be described as states.

Don't forget, you can't show sequences of actions and states by use cases elements only. If you have a small use case diagram, you could include state machine diagrams in it, but here it is not good - You have totally forgotten the admin and seller actors and their use cases, so the full use case diagram will be too large to add something extra in it. Describe sequences about logging in additional State Machine diagrams.